# Exporting an SPGridView to a document

Tags: sharepoint, wss, sharepoint-2007

I have a webpart which uses SPGridView to render tabulated data. I need to provide a button in the webpart, which upon clicking will export the SPGridView into a document, preferably, an Excel Sheet or a Word document. How do I export the data from an SPGridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html

I have used it for the SPGridView as well...

Answer (score 0):

To export to an .xls file look at [this sample code](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/SharePoint/microsoft.public.sharepoint.portalserver.development/2007-06/msg00048.html).

To export to a .csv file [here's another post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t366404-gridview-to-csv.html), it's for exporting from a GridView but should work for SPGridView as well.